# Test Camel Integration with JUnit

Tags: junit, apache-camel, integration-testing

I have a Camel integration flow. At one point, there is client creation, which is as following configuration:

```
<routeContext id="clientCreation" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route customId="true" id="clientCreationRouter">
        <from uri="direct:client-creation-start" customId="true" id="Client-Creation-Initiator"/>
        <bean ref="clientCreationService" method="constructClientDto" />
        <bean ref="clientCreationService" method="populateClientRequestMessage" />
        <bean ref="clientCreationService" method="saveClientDetails" />
        <bean ref="clientCreationService" method="createClientCreationFixedLengthMessage" />
        <setHeader headerName="flow-status" customId="true" id="Client-Creation-Update-Header">
             <simple>CLIENT_CREATED</simple>
        </setHeader>
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

`ConstructClientDto` has `FlowInfo` object as the input.

`createClientCreationFixedLengthMessage` has a `String` as the output. I want to test this part of the flow. Basically, I want to provide a `FlowInfo` object which is ready for Client-Creation and then see whether this part of the integration is successful based on the result provided at the end.

So far, this is what I tried:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (locations={"/META-INF/spring/data-extractor.xml",
        "/META-INF/spring/data-splitter.xml",
        "/META-INF/spring/client-creation.xml"})
public class ClientCreationFlowTest extends CamelTestSupport{

    @Produce (uri = "direct:client-creation-start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    FlowRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testClientCreation () throws Exception {
        FlowInfo flowInfo = repository.findById("1234");
        template.sendBody(resultEndpoint, flowInfo);
    }
}
```

When I run the test case, I get success. But when I debugged it, it does not seemed to be running through `ClientCreationService`. I am very new to Camel and the task is critical. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in your route definition you must send the result to `mock:result` at the end:

```
<routeContext id="clientCreation" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <route customId="true" id="clientCreationRouter">
        <from uri="direct:client-creation-start" customId="true" id="Client-Creation-Initiator"/>
        <bean ref="clientCreationService" method="constructClientDto" />
        <bean ref="clientCreationService" method="populateClientRequestMessage" />
        <bean ref="clientCreationService" method="saveClientDetails" />
        <bean ref="clientCreationService" method="createClientCreationFixedLengthMessage" />
        <setHeader headerName="flow-status" customId="true" id="Client-Creation-Update-Header">
             <simple>CLIENT_CREATED</simple>
        </setHeader>
        <to uri="mock:result"/>  
    </route>
</routeContext>
```

Second, in your JUnit test class you must not send the message to the mock endpoint but to `direct:client-creation-start` which is automatically done as the template is autowired with this uri:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration (locations={"/META-INF/spring/data-extractor.xml",
        "/META-INF/spring/data-splitter.xml",
        "/META-INF/spring/client-creation.xml"})
public class ClientCreationFlowTest extends CamelTestSupport{

    @Produce(uri = "direct:client-creation-start")
    protected ProducerTemplate template;

    @EndpointInject(uri = "mock:result")
    protected MockEndpoint resultEndpoint;

    @Autowired
    FlowRepository repository;

    @Test
    public void testClientCreation () throws Exception {
        FlowInfo flowInfo = repository.findById("1234");

        resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived("my string output");
        template.sendBody(flowInfo);
        resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `template.sendBody(flowInfo);` instead of directly sending it to the result endpoint, which bypasses your whole route.